# Confusing error message while using turtle in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm doing a CSP assignment for school and I was getting a rather confusing error message while I was testing whether the color portion of my code functioned.
This is my code:

```
import turtle
turtle = turtle.Turtle
turtle.color("brown")
```

And this is the error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/1ab7a960b2c10b4b/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    turtle.pencolor("brown")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2257, in pencolor
    return self._color(self._pencolor)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_color'
```

It does not make any bit of sense to me, as I am somewhat new to python.  Help?

Comment: This looks like an internal error of `turtle`, you could report this issue on their issue tracker, or look for a code snippet that does what you want in their documentation. Maybe you're doing things a bit unconventionally? (I have no specific experience with turtle)

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper not at all. You can't call an instance method as if it were a static / class method

Comment: Ah oops, I misread line 2 as `turtle.Turtle()`

Answer (score 2):

In the first line,  you import the `turtle` module.

In the second line, assign the `Turtle` class from the `turtle` module to the name `turtle`. This overwrites the value of the name `turtle`, so it no longer refers to the module -- it now refers to your `Turtle` class.

When you try to do `turtle.color`, you try to access the `color` function of `turtle`, which in this case is your `Turtle` class, instead of acting the `color` function of the `turtle` module, or the `color` method of an object of the `Turtle` class.
Note that an object of a class is not the same as the class itself.
Calling `Turtle.color("brown")` passes `"brown"` as the `self` argument, but the function expects the `self` argument to be an *object* of the `Turtle` class. This is why you see that error.

To fix this, assign a different name to your turtle so that you don't shadow the module. And remember to create an instance of the `Turtle` class by *calling* `turtle.Turtle()`, rather than just copying its value.

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle() # Create an instance, and assign it to a DIFFERENT name
my_turtle.color("brown")    # Call method of that instance
```

Comment: Also, you should highlight the difference between `turtle.Turtle` (which is a class) and `turtle.Turtle()` (which calls the class in order to create a new `Turtle` object). Shadowing the name is bad practice, but the actual error comes from looking the key `brown` up in the class rather than the object, leading to the `self` argument to `color` being the string `brown` rather than the expected Turtle object.

Comment: @rici I added a note, but I'm not sure how to explain the difference without giving a (somewhat too) in-depth explanation of classes and objects. Feel free to [edit] my answer if you'd like to improve it :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky to explain for beginners. Hopefully it's on the curriculum. But unless they get some basic explanation, they'll keep making the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The cause here is a common typographical error, but the error message is interesting enough to be worth an answer. (There might be a duplicate, but I'm not sure how to find it right now.)

`turtle.Turtle` is a class, i.e., a *type of data*, just like `int` or `str`.

By writing `turtle = turtle.Turtle`, we simply give the class another *name* (and also stop using that name for the module, which can cause other problems), rather than creating an instance. So the code `turtle.color("brown")` is trying to call the `color` method on the class, instead of the instance.

Instead, we want to *create an instance*, by calling the class: `turtle.Turtle()`. Then we should use a name for that which doesn't cause conflicts. Thus:

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle.color("brown")
```

Okay, but exactly *how* did it go wrong from there?

---

In Python, when the code looks for an *attribute* on some object (anything that follows the `.`), it looks in the object itself first, and then in the class. That's how method calls work normally: the object doesn't actually contain the method, but its class does. When something is found in the object's class instead of the object itself, then more steps are followed to make the method work like an actual method, rather than an ordinary function.

But also in Python, the classes themselves are objects. (That's why they can contain the methods.) So they have their own class (normally, the one named `type`), and their own attribute lookup process. The code `turtle.color("brown")` first tries to find `color` in the class (because that's what `turtle` currently names), and *finds it* (because it's looking directly in the class, and that's where it actually is). Since it was found directly, the method magic doesn't happen.

That means that `color` was called like an ordinary function, not like a method. Which means that the string `"brown"` is received as `self`.

Which means that the code in that method will try to use a string as if it were a `Turtle`, which it isn't. Which causes the error we see. `"brown"` is a `'str' object`, and it `has no attribute '_color'` (neither the string itself, nor the `str` class, contains it).